# Lodash _.hasIntersection?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I want to know if two or more arrays have common items, but I don't care what those items are. I know lodash has an `_.intersection` method, but I don't need it to run through every single item of each array. Instead, I need something like a `_.hasIntersection` method that will stop looking in an array once it finds the first common occurrence. Does lodash have something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach lets you efficiently search for an intersection in an arbitrary number of arrays.

```
function hasIntersection() {
    var collections = _.rest(arguments);

    return _.some(_.first(arguments), function(item) {
        return _(collections)
            .chain()
            .map(_.ary(_.partial(_.includes, item), 1))
            .compact()
            .size()
            .isEqual(collections.length)
            .value();
    });
}
```

The `hasIntersection()` function starts off by creating `collections`, these are the collections we want to look for intersecting values in, minus the first one. It returns the value of [some()](https://lodash.com/docs#some), which uses the [first()](https://lodash.com/docs#first) array argument to iterate over, the callback to `some()` compares all the other arrays passed to the function.

This is done by wrapping `collections` and building a call chain. It uses [chain()](https://lodash.com/docs#prototype-chain) to enable explicit chaining because we want to chain [isEqual()](https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual) to [size()](https://lodash.com/docs#size) at the end of the chain.

We map the `collections` variable, an array of arrays, to the [includes()](https://lodash.com/docs#includes) function. This results in an array of boolean values, true meaning that there's an intersecting value in one of the collections. The next step is to use [compact()](https://lodash.com/docs#compact) to remove falsey values. What we're left with is the the number of intersecting collections.

If the number of intersecting collections is the same length as `collections`, we've found a value that intersects across all collections, and can exit. This approach is efficient because of the short-circuits in place with `some()` and `includes()`

```
hasIntersection([ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 3 ]);
// → true

hasIntersection([ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 2, 4, 5 ], [ 2 ]);
// → true

hasIntersection([ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6 ], [ 7, 8 ]);
// → false
```

Comment: Coming back to this a couple of years later, this doesn't appear to work anymore. It seems `_.rest` expects a function. Was this a breaking change in lodash?

Comment: This demonstrates the problem: https://plnkr.co/edit/njV7Q4mqI4VP1SHyNGjK?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use [`some`](https://lodash.com/docs#some) and [`includes`](https://lodash.com/docs#includes):

```
var hasIntersection = _.some(arr1, _.ary(_.partial(_.includes, arr2), 1));
```