# indexOf with multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

Is it possible to use multiple arguments when determining `indexOf` on an array?

I want to determine if my array contains any of three integers. Important to note at this stage that the array will **only** have one value (if it has more, it won't reach this code block).

```
array.indexOf(123 || 124 || 125) === 0
```

So if `array = [123]` then my `indexOf` should be `0` and therefore `true`.

If `array = [124]` then my `indexOf` should be 0 and therefore `true`.

What I am finding is happening is `[123]` works OK but it's not even bothering to check the `indexOf` for the 2nd or 3rd arguments, and is just returning false.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WxmyGp?editors=0011

Comment: It wouldn't make much sense at all for `indexOf` to accept multiple arguments, e.g. `indexOf(1, 2, 3)`, because in the *general case*, what should the result be if multiple elements exist in the array…?

Comment: If you're open to using lodash, check out the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29416454/lodash-hasintersection

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `||` operator returns the left hand side if it is true, otherwise it returns the right hand side. `123 || 124 || 125` just means `123`.

If you want to test if any of multiple values are in an array, then you have to test each one in turn.

```
array.indexOf(123) == 0 || array.indexOf(124) == 0 || array.indexOf(125) == 0
```

Since you only care about one specific index the array, you can turn the whole thing on its head:

```
[123, 124, 125].indexOf(array[0]) > -1
```

Comment: @dave Both have `O(m * n)` complexity. Your approach just has `m` expressions joined by `||`s. Quentin's implementation appears to run considerably faster than yours in Chrome: https://plnkr.co/edit/yz9VRRJ3D0pIMqbSunJJ?p=preview

Comment: @JLRishe obviously those results speak for themselves, but I am having a hard time understanding why. I posted a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39006845/how-can-array-indexof-be-more-efficient-than-array-some) to ask why that approach is faster.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

The nice thing about this approach is that you will only have to iterate through the array once. If you `||` multiple `indexOf()` calls together, you're going to keep iterating the array with every missed search.

```js
function checkArray(array) {
  return array.some(function(item) {
    return item == 123 || item == 124 || item == 125;
  });
};

console.log(checkArray([123, 456, 789]));
console.log(checkArray([456, 789]));
console.log(checkArray([789, 456, 125]));
```

Comment: If I read the Q correctly, the solution would be a simple `array == [123] || array == [124] || array == [125]`.

Comment: @Boldewyn — No. `==` tests if both sides are the same object. Different arrays won't match even if they are identical.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get multiple results one other way of doing this is `Array.prototype.filter()`. Bu this will return you the objects itself. If you are interested in the indices then you have to combine it with `Array.prototype.reduce()` such as;

```js
var a = [1,2,3],
    b = a.filter(e => e === 1 || e === 2)
         .reduce((p,c) => p.concat(a.indexOf(c)),[]);
console.log(b);
```