# Cant use || or && properly in indexOf?

Tags: javascript

```
 myName = 'Hi! my name is Master';
 indexOf_myName = myName.indexOf('no' && 'Master');
 console.log(indexOf_myName);
```

If i use this code i get the index of "Master" but not if i put "Master && no", also I cant use ||, it always return -1

Comment: _"That's normal or a JS bug?"_ - Just read the documentation for [`.indexOf(searchString[, position])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: consider what is the return value of `&&` operator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [indexOf with multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39000151/indexof-with-multiple-arguments)

Comment: i should get -1 because i dont have no and master at the same time in the string, but i get anyway the index of master. Thats the thing i dont understand.

Comment: You are using indexOf and the && operator wrong. indexOf only accepts a string. You are passing a boolean, as the result of 'no' && 'Master' which is true

Comment: @MKougiouris `'no' && 'Master'` returns a string, not a boolean.

Comment: You are correct, it returns 'Master' a simple console here verified it

Comment: 'Hi! my name is Master'.indexOf('no' && 'Master') returns 15

Comment: It would be useful if you explained, in your question, what you _expect_ that code should do.  Disclosing your expectations is especially useful to someone trying to clarify your misunderstanding when you ask something like "is that a JS bug?"

Comment: Just a guess that the OP really wants to read about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes, and the expression being sought is `myName.includes('no') && myName.includes('Master')`, or the disjunction `myName.includes('no') || myName.includes('Master')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const myName = 'Hi! my name is Master'
console.log( myName.indexOf( 'no' && 'Master' ) ) // 15
console.log( myName.indexOf( 'Master' && 'no' ) ) // -1
```

indexOf returns -1 if the string is not found

'no' is not in `myName`, therefore it returns -1

---

```js
console.log( myName.indexOf( 'no' && 'foo' && 'bar' && 'Master' ) ) // 15
console.log( myName.indexOf( 'no' || 'foo' || 'bar' || 'Master' ) ) // -1
console.log( myName.indexOf( 'Master' && 'foo' && 'bar' && 'no' ) ) // -1
console.log( myName.indexOf( 'Master' || 'foo' || 'bar' || 'no' ) ) // 15
```

##### `&&`

returns the last truthy value if all values are truthy

##### `||`

returns the first truthy value if any value is truthy

```js
myName.indexOf( 'no' || 'foo' || 'bar' || 'Master' ) // -1
// same as
myName.indexOf( 'no' ) // -1
```

```js
myName.indexOf( 'no' && 'foo' && 'bar' && 'Master' ) // 15
// same as
myName.indexOf( 'Master' ) // 15
```

---

#### More details

##### `&&`

checks every value in the expression, then if all of them are truthy, it returns the last value

##### `||`

checks each value (from left to right) until it reaches a truthy value, then it returns that truthy value and doesn't evaluate the rest of the values

Comment: Maybe im not understanding you.
"|| returns the first truthy value if any value is truthy"
In that case why i get -1 in:
console.log( myName.indexOf( 'no' || 'foo' || 'bar' || 'Master' ) ) // -1
Master is a truthy value. I should get 15 right?

Comment: The logical OR is a binary operator, i.e. it applies to two operands. If you have `1 || 2 || 3`, then first `1 || 2` is evaluated, and the result is evaluated to `|| 3`. "[_If expr1 can be converted to true, returns expr1; else, returns expr2._](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR)". So it will return the first truthy value, which is `'no'`, not `'master'`.